# Is it better to send big messages in python socket by chunks?

Tags: python, sockets

I send with socket images of my screen. Because it is a big message, it takes a lot of time for the socket.send() function to send the images. Will the send function work better if I send the images by chunks.

Comment: No. You should treat a TCP connection as a byte stream.